# Can someone pleaase clarify the meaning of the code mentioned below?

Tags: tcl

```
$pipe revolve -angle 360 $line {0 0 0} {1 0 0}
```

I will try to convert tcl code in to python.

I tried to make cyclinder.

Comment: If I understand correctly (I'm just guessing here), pipe is a python command, -angle 360 means you're creating a solid of revolution with some shape, and the revolution is going a full 360 degrees around. The line seems to imply the shape you're revolving around is a line (or rather line segment), and the {0 0 0} {1 0 0} specify the endpoints of the line. In theory, if you revolve a line around an axis, you often create a cylinder. Technically, though, depending on which way you rotate, you can either create a cylinder, another line, a disk, a cone, or a hyperboloid. Which did you get?

Comment: I would like to create a cylinder.

Comment: I ask because, since this line intersects the origin, if you try rotating it around the origin, you'll either get a line, a disk, or a cone, depending on which axis you revolve around. However, if you didn't get any shape at all, that is another issue entirely. I apologize if I got too ahead of myself.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest model of conversion gives you:

```py
pipe.revolve(line, (0,0,0), (1,0,0), angle=360)
```

`$pipe` obviously refers to some object. `$line` is something; don't know what beyond "read from this variable". `revolve` is a method of the class that `$pipe` is an instance of. Tcl uses lists for tuples (which is fine; Tcl lists are immutable in the ways that Python tuples are) so those coordinates translate best like that. Tcl does keyword arguments quite differently to Python, but the concepts exist on both sides.

Which is not to say that whatever object `pipe` is an instance of will accept that.

---

It's typically a really bad idea to try to translate a program one line at a time. Yes, you can do it, but you tend to miss out entirely on how you *should* convert things; different languages have entirely different idioms.

Comment: It's *possible* that this conversion is wrong, and that `angle` takes multiple arguments following it. Unlikely (that model of argument parsing isn't particularly popular in Tcl outside of some Tk commands as it is a bit of a pain to parse) but possible.

Comment: FYI, it appears that this is Glyph for Pointwise http://www.pointwise.com/glyph2/files/Glyph/cxx/GgGlyph-cxx.html which is a tool for "meshing", but I'm familiar with what that is!